# Lifecycle methods of UIViewController subclass in renamed storyboard are never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm not instantiating my controls/views manually. I've set up a storyboard like this:

```
-> UITabBarController-> UINavigationController-> HomeViewController
```

I switched the controller class of the last to my own HomeViewController.

Here's the code:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *buttonView;
    UITableView *buttonTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *buttonView;

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize buttonView;
```

Inside the main view for HomeViewController there's a subview (`UIView`) that is hooked up to the outlet by ctrl-dragging one of those lines.

But I can't for my life find a method on `UIViewController` to override that will be invoked somewhere in the life cycle. So far I've tried putting my stuff in

```
// didn't expect it to work
-(id)init

// didn't expect it to work
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

// had hopes for this one, but no such luck
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

// this one looked promising...
-(id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

// not much hope
-(void)awakeFromNib {

// my main candidate for a long while...
-(void)viewDidLoad {
```

When I run the interface loads perfectly, I get my tabs, my navigation bar, my view. But no matter how much `NSLog()` I do in `HomeViewController` there's never any output in the console.

Am I missing something about the lifecycle of the storyboard? Is my controller not instantiated or used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I recently renamed the storyboard and didn't realise Xcode does not rename the `Main Storyboard` setting. I've cleaned the project numerous times and still it seems the old storyboard is present and loaded.

[image: settings that is wrong]

Answer (score 3):

viewDidLoad is called with a storyboard,  something is wrong with your storyboard setup.  Sounds like it is loading a standard UIViewController rather than your HomeViewController subclass. Make sure the HomeViewController class setup in the storyboard.

Comment: Found the problem after a night's sleep. I've renamed the storyboard and apparently Xcode doesn't rename the `Main Storyboard` setting.